# Prove $z=1+e^{\frac{2i \pi}{3}}=e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}$

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

I passed by a question that asks to prove the following equality in 3 different methods, I knew two of them, but I couldn't figure out the third one. If there are more than three, I would love to know as many as possible.

$z=1+e^{\frac{2i \pi}{3}}=e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}$

The first method is switching everything into algebraic form, simplifying it and then changing it back to exponential form.

The second method is to take common and write it as follows,

$z=1+e^{\frac{2i \pi}{3}}=e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}(2×\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})) =e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}$

What else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $x=e^{\frac{i\pi}3}$, then $x^3=e^{i\pi}=-1$, and $x$ is complex number, which is not real.

So $x\ne-1$, then $0=x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$.

$x^2+1=x$, so $1+e^{\frac{2i\pi}3}=e^{\frac{i\pi}3}$.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a picture of the complex plane with the points $0, 1, e^\frac{i\pi}3, e^\frac{2i\pi}3$ marked out.

Use Euclidean geometry to argue that they form a parallelogram.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Taylor series of $1+e^{2ix}$ and $e^{ix}$ and show that they are the same when $x=\pi/3$. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If you solve the equation $1+x^2=x$, you will see that it only has two solutions: $e^{i\pi/3}$ and $e^{2\pi i/3}$.

Therefore, $1+\left(e^{\pi i/3}\right)^2=e^{\pi i/3}$; in other words, $1+e^{2\pi i/3}=e^{\pi i/3}$.

Answer (score 0):

A point $ \ z \ = \ \alpha + i\beta \ \ $ is to be translated to the right by one unit, so that the modulus of $ \ z' \  = \ \alpha' + i\beta $ $ = \ (1 + \alpha) + i\beta \ \ $  is unchanged.  Thus,
$$  |z|^2 \ \ = \ \ \alpha^2 + \beta^2 \ \ = \ \ |z'|^2 \ \  = \ \ (1 + \alpha)^2 + \beta^2 \ \ \Rightarrow  \ \ 1 + 2 \alpha \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \alpha \ \ = \ \ -\frac12 \ \ . $$

Geometrically in the Argand plane, the vectors (from the origin) $ \ z \ , \ z' \ , \ $ and $ \ 1 \ $ form the sides of an isosceles triangle symmetrical about the $ \ \mathfrak{Im}-$axis.  The vector $ \ z \ $ makes an angle $ \ \theta \ = \  \pi + \arctan \left(\frac{\beta}{-1/2} \right) \ $ to the positive $ \ \mathfrak{Re}-$axis, while $ \ z' \ $ makes an angle  $ \ \theta' \ = \ \arctan \left(\frac{\beta}{1/2} \right) \ $ to that direction.  Writing $ \ \rho \ = \ |z|  \ =  \ |z'| \ \ , \ $ we have $ \ z \ = \ \rho·e^{\ i·\theta} \ \ , \ \ z' \ = \ \rho·e^{\ i·\theta'} \ \ . $

If we now require that $ \ z \ $ have *unit* modulus, then
$$ \alpha^2  +  \beta^2 \ \ = \ \ \left(-\frac12 \right)^2 + \beta^2 \ \ = \ \ 1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \beta^2 \ \ = \ \ \frac34 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  \beta \ \ = \ \ \pm \frac{\sqrt3}{2} \ \ . $$
Hence, $ \ \theta \ = \  \pi + \arctan ( \ \mp \sqrt3 \ ) \ = \ \pi \mp \frac{\pi}{3} \ = \ \frac{2 \pi}{3} \ , \ \frac{4 \pi}{3} \ $ and $ \ \theta' \ = \  \arctan ( \ \pm \sqrt3 \ ) \ = \ \pm \frac{\pi}{3} \ = \ \frac{ \pi}{3} \ , \ \frac{5 \pi}{3} \ \ . $  We have then $ \ 1  \ + \  1·e^{\ i·2 \pi/3 } \ = \ 1·e^{\ i·\pi/3 }  $  and also $ \ 1  \ + \  1·e^{\ i·4 \pi/3 } \ = \ 1·e^{\ i·5\pi/3 } \ \ . $   From the aforementioned (infinite implied) family of isosceles triangles in the Argand plane, we have "selected" the two that are *equilateral*.

(We could also argue that the translation of $ \ z \ $ by one unit "to the right" is then equivalent to a rotation *clockwise* of the vector $ \ z \ $ by the angle $ \ \frac{\pi}{3} \ \ , \ $ or $ \  e^{\ i·2 \pi/3 } \ + \ 1 \ = \ e^{\ i·2 \pi/3 }·e^{\ -i·\pi/3 } \ = \ e^{\ i·\pi/3 } \ \ . ) $